# Find and replace using Openpyxl

Tags: python, replace, openpyxl

I am trying to replace anything in column C that has `-1` as a value to `0`. Here is what I have tried so far. I am new to python and openpyxl so please be patient with me.

```py
import openpyxl
    excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx')
    sheet1 = excelFile.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
    currentRow = 1
    for eachRow in sheet1.iter_rows():
        if sheet1.cell(currentRow, column=3) == '-1':
            sheet1.cell(row=currentRow, column=3).value = "0"
            currentRow += 1
            excelFile.save('C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx')
```

I have also tried this with the same result, no errors however no changes to the file.

```
import openpyxl
excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx')
sheet1 = excelFile.get_sheet_by_name('CFRP_1_21')

if sheet1['C:C'] == '-1':
    sheet1['C:C'] = '0'
    excelFile.save('C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx')
```

Comment: And what is the result of this code? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a quicker response. One tip, use raw strings when using directories in Windows, for example instead of `openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx')` use: `openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx')`. Otherwise, the backslashes will be looked at as parts of a string, not a folder/file location.

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it runs with no errors however no changes to the file are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [openpyxl tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html), it should help clear up some basic usage questions you may have.

**Try this for your use-case:**

```py
import openpyxl
excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx')
#sheet1 = excelFile.get_sheet_by_name('CFRP_1_21')
sheet1 = excelFile.active #This selects the first sheet in the Excel file, only use specific names if required

for col in sheet1.iter_cols(min_col=3, min_row=1, max_col=3):
    for cell in col:
        if cell.value == '-1':
            cell.value = '0'
excelFile.save(r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\file\file.xlsx') #Don't forget to use 'r' for string here
```

Comment: Thank you I just had to change cell.value == '-1': 
cell.value == 1.0: